# socketio.AsyncServer() and Flask integration

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I want to use socketio.AsyncServer in Flask application, but not sure how to integrate it. (SocketIO works fine for me)

Here is partial code

```
from flask import Flask
import socketio

app = Flask(__name__)

# Is configuration correct for Flask and socketio.AsyncServer?
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins="*") 

(how to integrate sio with app here?)

app.run(debug=True)
```

How to integrate sio object with Flask app object?

Here is references, but no solution is found:

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/python-socketio.1.html
https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, python-socketio doesn't have a direct integration with flask async at the moment. So you either need to integrate a Flask-SocketIO with a sync client (can be patched with gevent or eventlet).

Is it a production application where you expect a high load? If not, I would most certainly suggest to use Flask-SocketIO https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ as it is a very convenient integration for simple MVP needs.

If it is a production application and you want to avoid having extra dependencies and don't plan to benefit from Flask authentication within your python-socketio instance, I would suggest to decouple your Flask application from SocketIO app and use an async client with a deployment of your choice https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/server.html#uvicorn-daphne-and-other-asgi-servers.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The reason I want such integration: a python client uses socketio.AsyncClient. I tried SocketIO on server with client with socketio.Client, and could not make file chunk transfer to work reliably: lost packet, and packet sequence is not guaranteed, not exactly sure if it's my code issue or such setup won't work for chunk transfer. Those are 2 different libs (SocketIO and asyncio), right? I guess I have to use aiohttp to replace my Flask server, as I already have code that can transfer file chunks reliably with aiohttp as server.

Comment: socket.AsyncClient and socketAsyncServer with aiohttp has no issue of implementing chunked file transfer (no lost packet, chunk arrives in same order as it's sent). The reason to use socket.AsyncServer in a web server is that UI requests a file which is in a python client, the REST API in web server needs to wait all chunks are received, which requires async function to be implemented inside REST API.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why exactly there is a need to couple the aiohttp application with socketio application as I don't know what is the relation between REST API server that I assume is written in aiohttp in your case and socketio.

Unfortunately, it is hard for me to provide more help without the code samples, as we talk a bit in vacuum.

And yes, SocketIO and asyncio are two different libraries

Comment: The web app has REST API to serve web pages. That's the reason I am looking for the web server framework to be integrated with socketioAsync. User click a button, the web server uses socketio to load file in a Python client by chunks, which is connected to the web server.

Comment: I suggest to decouple these too applications and serve your Flask application on one port and socketio on the other port.

Comment: If running on different ports, they will run on different threads? If that's the case, above scenario will become complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncServer` class from python-socketio is incompatible with Flask. If you want to use the async server, then look for an asyncio compatible web framework (aiohttp, fastapi, etc.).

The AsyncServer can be made into an ASGI application on its own as well, so you can run it on a ASGI web server (uvicorn) without any web framework.